# Ionic 4 navigate after click not firing, need to click multiple times

Tags: android, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a list of items (40 of them) that load a page which describe the content of an item (like photos, url link and other). But the problem is, I have to click like two to three times to get to this page. I do think that the page use a lot of html component so it takes longer to load.

If somebody could help me if it's a problem of lazyloading or ionic view lifecycle.

Thank you in advance !

**Ionic 4 List of Items :**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start"><ion-back-button></ion-back-button></ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{global.p.pro}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let r of result">

      <ion-list>

        <ion-item button (click)="onPro(r);">
          <ion-avatar>
            <img [src]="r.icon"/>
          </ion-avatar>
          <ion-label>
            <h2>{{r.name}}</h2>
            <h3>{{r.vicinity}}</h3>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-button *ngIf="r.opening_hours !== undefined" slot="end" [color]="r.open" (click)="onPro(r);">{{r.opening_hours.open_now ? 'Ouvert': 'Fermé'}}</ion-button>
          <ion-button *ngIf="r.opening_hours === undefined" (click)="onPro(r);"> Incertain</ion-button>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>

    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
<ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" *ngIf="isInfinite">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles"
  loadingText="Recherche en cours..."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

**Ionic 4 Page to load**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start" ><ion-back-button defaultHref="" routerLink="/listpro" routerDirection="back"></ion-back-button></ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{elt.name}}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-badge *ngIf="elt.opening_hours !== undefined" [color]="elt.open">{{elt.opening_hours.open_now ? 'Ouvert': 'Fermé'}}</ion-badge>
      <ion-badge *ngIf="elt.opening_hours === undefined">Incertain</ion-badge>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600"/>

    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
  <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
    <ion-button size="block" (click)="onPhone();">Contactez</ion-button>
    <ion-button size="block" (click)="onAdress();">Itinéraire</ion-button>
    <div *ngIf="profil.rating !== undefined">
    <rating [rate]="profil.rating"
        readonly="true" 
        size="default">
    </rating>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="profil.rating === undefined" style="text-align: center;">
    Aucune Note Utilisateur...
  </div>
  <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
  <h2>Horaires d'ouverture :</h2>
  <div *ngIf="profil.opening_hours !== undefined"><div *ngFor="let w of profil.opening_hours.weekday_text" style="text-align: center;"> {{w}}</div></div>
  <div *ngIf="profil.opening_hours === undefined" style="text-align: center;">Aucune Information...</div>
  <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
  <div *ngIf="profil.website !== undefined"><h2>Site Web :</h2><a [href]="profil.website">{{profil.website}}</a></div>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: try to run your for loop `*ngFor="let r of result"` on your `ion-item` tag. and check if it still takes 2, 3 clicks.

Comment: I try it and it does not chane anything... Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround ! I use a loading boolean that is true is everything in the ts is loaded, so i can have an empty html with ngIf. After everything is loaded, it shows all the information. Thank you everyone !